# My card container is moving down when I click a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a problem with my code and I don't know if it's a css issue or a js issue. When I click the button of my page, my card-container2 is moving down. Here's all my code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="card-container">
    <h1>splitter bill</h1>
    <p>enter the name of the person and his amount (21% of iva included):</p>
    <label id="name-text">Nombre</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <br>
    <label id="monto-texto">amount</label>
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="amount">
    <br>
    <button id="calculate">Ingresar</button>
    <p>Total: <span id="total"></span> </p>
    <div id="each-person">
    </div>
    <p> Cada uno le toca aportar: <span id="split"></span> </p>
</div>
<div class="card-container2">
    <div id="clima">   
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
//there is more js code if you need 
function defineTotal() {

  personsListHTMLelemento = "";

  let list = "";
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    total += persons[i].amount
    list += `${persons[i].name}: ${persons[i].amount} <br>`;
  }

  let iva = 1.21

  totalHTMLelemento.innerHTML = total * iva;
  personsListHTMLelemento.innerHTML = list;
  splitHTMLelemento.innerHTML = (total * iva) / persons.length;
```

CSS:

```css
.card-container {
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-right: 500px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    background-color: #302b63;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.card-container2 {
    margin-left: 1270px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    background-color: #302b63;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: -490px;
}
```

If you need more of my CSS/JavaScript code, let me know and i will post it

Comment: What would be better is if you edit your post and put this code in a snippet.  The snippet tool is a box with **<>** in it.

Answer (score 1):

i couldnt get the error to duplicate but if the above is your code, your missing a    } at the end of your script.

```js
function defineTotal() {

personsListHTMLelemento = "";

let list = "";
let total = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  total += persons[i].amount
  list += `${persons[i].name}: ${persons[i].amount} <br>`;
}

let iva = 1.21

totalHTMLelemento.innerHTML = total * iva;
personsListHTMLelemento.innerHTML = list;
splitHTMLelemento.innerHTML = (total * iva) / persons.length;
    }
```

```css
  .card-container {
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-right: 500px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    background-color: #302b63;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.card-container2 {
    margin-left: 1270px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    background-color: #302b63;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: -490px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
    <h1>splitter bill</h1>
    <p>enter the name of the person and his amount (21% of iva included):</p>
    <label id="name-text">Nombre</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <br>
    <label id="monto-texto">amount</label>
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="amount">
    <br>
    <button id="calculate">Ingresar</button>
    <p>Total: <span id="total"></span> </p>
    <div id="each-person">
    </div>
    <p> Cada uno le toca aportar: <span id="split"></span> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container2">
      <div id="clima">   
      </div>
   </div>
```